# Qt: Understanding QScrollArea::widgetResizable property

Tags: qt, qscrollarea

I am experimenting with Qt 5 `QScrollArea` (in Python and PyQt, but I believe the question applies just as well in C++ Qt).

The [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html#widgetResizable-prop) for `QScrollArea::widgetResizable` says that "If this property is set to false (the default), the scroll area honors the size of its widget." By "its widget", I assume it means the widget being viewed in the scroll area.

However, in the program below I show an image label inside the scroll area, but the scroll area does not seem to "honor the size of its widget", because the image is partly hidden from the start.

The documentation also says "Regardless of this property, you can programmatically resize the widget using `widget()->resize()`, and the scroll area will automatically adjust itself to the new size." However, I do invoke resize for the viewed widget, but nothing happens.

The documentation also says "If this property is set to true, the scroll area will automatically resize the widget in order to avoid scroll bars where they can be avoided, or to take advantage of extra space." However, I don't see any resizing, even though if the widget were resized then it would be possible to avoid the scroll bars.

This is what I see whether I set the property to `True` or `False`, and whether I invoke `widget().resize()` or not:

[image]

Clearly I must be missing something quite fundamental here; what is it?

***Edit***: the main purpose of the question is understanding how `widgetResizable` works and what it does. Fitting the image into the window is a secondary goal.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPalette, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QLabel, QScrollArea


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        image = QImage("happyguy.png")
        imageLabel = QLabel()
        imageLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))

        scrollArea = QScrollArea()
        scrollArea.setBackgroundRole(QPalette.Dark)
        scrollArea.setWidget(imageLabel)

        scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)

        scrollArea.widget().resize(QSize(10, 10))

        self.setCentralWidget(scrollArea)


app = QApplication([])
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

And here's the `happyguy.pgn` file:

[image: happyguy.pgn]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)` give the resize control of imageLabel to scrollArea. So the next line `scrollArea.widget().resize(QSize(10, 10))` will be overrode by system.

A solution worked on windows (resize main window to fit image size).

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPalette, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QLabel, QScrollArea, QFrame


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        image = QImage("happyguy.png")
        imageLabel = QLabel()
        imageLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))

        scrollArea = QScrollArea()
        scrollArea.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        scrollArea.setBackgroundRole(QPalette.Dark)
        scrollArea.setWidget(imageLabel)

        self.setCentralWidget(scrollArea)
        self.resize(image.size())


app = QApplication([])
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

**Or** use `QScrollArea.setMinimumSize`

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPalette, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QLabel, QScrollArea, QFrame


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        image = QImage("happyguy.png")
        imageLabel = QLabel()
        imageLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))

        scrollArea = QScrollArea()
        scrollArea.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        scrollArea.setBackgroundRole(QPalette.Dark)
        scrollArea.setWidget(imageLabel)
        scrollArea.setMinimumSize(image.size())

        self.setCentralWidget(scrollArea)


app = QApplication([])
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score -1):

**Resizable** IS NOT **Scrollable** ...

Comment: The question remains as to what that setting is doing, as no changes are observed.